# I want to change default settings of '2d animation'

Tags: grease-pencil

[image]

I made a new '2d animation' file with ctrl+n and default setting looks like above picture.

I want to change color and size of white panel and color of background.[image]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Color 2 is the world color.

[image]

You can set the size of the camera canvas in the render resolution panel (and then use scroll wheel or Ctrl + Middle Mouse Button to scale the view in the 3d window).

[image]
Color 1 is a viewport matte with transparency, it can be set going in object mode, selecting the camera, and varying its "passepartout" value.

[image]

Then you can go to the file menu, defaults, save startup file, to mantain your settings in any new project.

Comment: your answer is perfect. thank you.